# What is the best way of sorting sequentially column after column for 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting

Let's say I have a `mx3` 2D array, what I want is:

1. First sort the array according to its last column (the column indexed 2).
2. Find all the array slices whose values in the last column are the same, sort each array slice according to the column in the middle.
3. Find all the array slices in which the two values in the last two columns are the same among rows, sort each array slice according to the first column.

An example of this sorting is like

[image: example]

Below is the solution I came up with, which essentially implements the quick-sort algorithm:

```
def quicksort(array, c_ind, begin=0, end=None):
    
    def _partition(array, c_ind, begin, end):
        pivot = begin
        for i in range(begin+1, end+1):
            if array[i][c_ind] <= array[begin][c_ind]:
                pivot += 1
                array[i], array[pivot] = array[pivot], array[i]
        array[pivot], array[begin] = array[begin], array[pivot]
        
        return pivot
    
    def _quicksort(array, c_ind, begin, end):    
        if begin >= end: return
        pivot = _partition(array, c_ind, begin, end)
        _quicksort(array, c_ind, begin, pivot-1)
        _quicksort(array, c_ind, pivot+1, end)
        
    if end is None: end = len(array)-1
        
    return _quicksort(array, c_ind, begin, end)


def solver(array):
    
    num_columns = len(array[0])
    for column_ind in range(num_columns)[::-1]:
        
        if column_ind == num_columns - 1:
            quicksort(array,c_ind=column_ind)
        else:
            for post_ind in range(len(posts)-1):
                quicksort(array,c_ind=column_ind,begin=posts[post_ind],end=posts[post_ind+1]-1)
    
        posts = [0]
        for row_ind,row in enumerate(array):
            if row_ind == 0: 
                previous_val = tuple([row[c_idx] for c_idx in range(column_ind,num_columns)[::-1]])
            if row_ind > 0:
                if tuple([row[c_idx] for c_idx in range(column_ind,num_columns)[::-1]]) != previous_val:
                    posts.append(row_ind)
                previous_val = tuple([row[c_idx] for c_idx in range(column_ind,num_columns)[::-1]])
        posts.append(len(array))        
            
array = [[1,1,1,0,0,2,3,1,4],[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1],[1,1,2,3,4,5,1,1,1]]
print(np.array(array).T,'\n')
array = np.array(array).T.tolist()

solver(array)
np.array(array)
```

Have I done it correctly? And more importantly, is there a `numpy` module that can do this for me?

Comment: Look at `np.lexsort`.  Structured arrays also do that style of sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lexsort:

```
array[np.lexsort((array[:,-3],array[:,-2],array[:,-1]))]
```

or equivalently (and especially for larger arrays):

```
array[np.lexsort(array.T)]
```

example:

```
array = 
[[1 0 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 0 2]
 [0 0 3]
 [0 0 4]
 [2 0 5]
 [3 1 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [4 1 1]]
```

output:

```
[[1 0 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 1]
 [3 1 1]
 [4 1 1]
 [1 0 2]
 [0 0 3]
 [0 0 4]
 [2 0 5]]
```